# How to add window button to android toolbar?

Tags: android-toolbar

first look at this picture

[image]

As you can see there is a button in toolbar like windows icon
i want to add this button without any layout and...
just like share button
i dont want create layout or icon by myself i want pre designed button like that
just like this code for share button

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/shareicon"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

please help me tnx.

Comment: You can try [this](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/windows) or [this](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/view-grid) whichever suits your need. But this is not the kind of question you should be asking on StackOverflow. Please go through the How to Ask section.

Comment: tnx but i dont want to create the button by my self i can do that but i want code like up there

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "code like up there." The links I posted direct you to "pre designed" png/xml resources for the icons. You wouldn't have to "create the button", you can download it.

Comment: i mean if you put that code on menu_main.xml and run the app you can see you have share button on your toolbar this code make the button by itself i dont want any icon or somthing like that i just wannna code like that to create window button for me

Comment: test the code and you can know what i saying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here is what you have to do:

Download the icon from the preferred link and place it in your drawable folder. Assuming you have named it "ic_window", here is the code that would do what you want:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_window"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_window"
    android:title="@string/action_window"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

In your code, what puts the icon on the menu item is the line `app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"`. According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html):

> To add a "share" action to your activity, put a ShareActionProvider in the app bar's menu resource.
>
> You do not need to specify an icon, since the ShareActionProvider widget takes care of its own appearance and behavior. However, you do need to specify a title with `android:title`, in case the action ends up in the overflow menu.

There is no "window" icon in the default android resources AFAIK. Hence you need to create/download the icon you need.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: that is the point i dont want download icon for it i did this as well before now i want to know is there any code like up there (share button) or not. (that code dosen't need any icon or somthing just you put that to main_menu.xml and it's done).